# Backbone call DELETE API without an ID

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I have an API to delete a list of objects by passing the object IDs (API URL: DELETE /item/deleteall?ids=1,2,3). In backbone deleting individual is possible by calling the destroy method, but how can I call the above end point?

```
define(['backbone'], function(Backbone) {

    var ItemsDelete = Backbone.Model.extend({
        urlRoot: '/item/deleteall'
    });

    return ItemsDelete;
});

var itemsDelete = new ItemsDelete();
itemsDelete.destroy({...}); //this doesn't call the end point
```

If this is not possible or not the best way of doing it, please suggest alternatives. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't really make sense to use a Backbone model as a way to call a custom endpoint to delete multiple objects, as a model exist to manage one object.

The [`destroy` method](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/8ec88604732944f197b352a6be22c8216ea9d3a1/backbone.js#L676) is made accordingly to avoid calling the endpoint if the model is new (no `id` attribute yet).

> ```
> var xhr = false;
> if (this.isNew()) {
>     // here it skips the API call
>     _.defer(options.success);
> } else {
>     wrapError(this, options);
>     xhr = this.sync('delete', this, options);
> }
> ```

It would probably make more sense to make your own `destroy` function on a collection.

```
// An item model
var Item = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: '/item',
});

// the collection
var ItemCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Item,
    destroy: function(options) {
        options = options || {};
        var ids = options.models || this.pluck(this.model.prototype.idAttribute);

        // use the existing `sync` to make the ajax call
        this.sync('delete', this, _.extend({
            url: _.result(this.model.prototype, 'urlRoot') + "/deleteall",
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify(ids),
        }, options));


        this.remove(ids, options);
    }
});
```

Then, you could use it like this:

```
var testCollection = new ItemCollection([{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }, ]);

// destroy specific ids
testCollection.destroy({
    models: [1, 2, 3]
});

// destroy all models inside the collection
testCollection.destroy();
```

The ids are in the body of the request, they shouldn't be in the url as the `DELETE` http verb affects the server state.

[image: ids in the body of the request]